# No update when i use .update() in powershell for Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I use this code for update the Search Settings of all webs pages of a url site set in a parameter in IE powershell, for update settings of Sharepoint Online.

[image]

But, it don't work when i use $sWeb.update because i go to this pages and i don't see any change.

Someone have an idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After `update` you need to call `ExecuteQuery` so that the changes get sent over to the Server.

Comment: I do a ExecuteQuery after update but it doesn't work.

Comment: Any other idea why doesn't it works?